# line height for % height

Tags: html, css, height, vertical-alignment

When I want to center text vertically in div, add line-height for example;

```
<div class="text"> Text </div>
```

```css
.text{
   height:50px;
   line-height:50px;
 }
```

But if height:5%, how to give a value for line-height to center text vertically in div?

Comment: the `height` and `line-height` properties value must be the same. And the elements should be under a table in order for `vertically-align` property to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you wich to center text in the middle of the div just add :

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

to your div and it will allign it in the middle vertically.

**CSS**

```
<div class="text"> Text </div>
```

```css
.text{
   height:50px;
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
 }
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/JaP22/

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working properly with percentages, not sure why.  Thought it might have been because the anonymous table/table-row didn't have a height, but adding actual table/table-row elements didn't seem to help:  http://jsfiddle.net/JaP22/1/